# Setting another keyboard as default keyboard from my app

Tags: android

Inside the setting screen, there is a **"Language & Input option"** .

> Inside the "Language & Input" , we have a default option where we can
>   select any keyboard (default or 3rd party) .I want that selection of
>   keyboard programatically in my app .

Like if we have 2 soft keyboards(default and keyboard A) . Then in my activity when i presses a button it should make keyboard A as running .

Answer (score 0):

Kaddy UrAdmirer..

As per I knew we can't set default softkeyboard programatically. But we can open `InputMethodPicker` Dialog.

Here is below code for open InputMethodPicker dialog

```
InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
if (imeManager != null) {
    imeManager.showInputMethodPicker();

} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have this in the application (see why [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/ZAvbAKU8Gbg/dFtEnxe4aQUJ)), instead, you can put a Dialog and suggest to the user to go there and change it.